# Using CV_MAT_ELEM for modifying CvMat* pixels

Tags: c, opencv

I am trying to create a kernel used for the Filter2D function. That function expects the kernel to be in CvMat format.

How do I access elements of the CvMat? I have the following code, which gives a compiler error.

```
inline void plot(CvMat* mat, int x, int y, float c)
//plot the pixel at (x, y) with brightness c (where 0 ≤ c ≤ 1)
{
    CV_MAT_ELEM(mat,float,y,x) = MIN(c,1); //The error occurs at this line
}
```

I get the following errors:

> error C2228: left of '.data' must have class/struct/union
>   error C2228: left of '.ptr' must have class/struct/union
>   error C2228: left of '.step' must have class/struct/union

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not a duplicate because OpenCV has different interfaces and data structures, a C-style and a C++ interface. This is about using the C matrix implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: dereference the pointer you pass to the macro:

```
CV_MAT_ELEM(*mat,float,y,x) = MIN(c,1);
```